# JSON php extract data (where a statement is true)

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm trying to catch specific data from a weather  forecast API request (JSON output). The request gives me data for the next 3 days but I only need the next day. Here a snippet of the output:

```
array (
  'cod' => '200',
  'message' => 0.00259999999999999988065102485279567190445959568023681640625,
  'cnt' => 40,
  'list' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'dt' => 1526461200,
      'main' => 
      array (
        'temp' => 292.93000000000000682121026329696178436279296875,
        'temp_min' => 292.05000000000001136868377216160297393798828125,
        'temp_max' => 292.93000000000000682121026329696178436279296875,
        'pressure' => 1019.259999999999990905052982270717620849609375,
        'sea_level' => 1029.170000000000072759576141834259033203125,
        'grnd_level' => 1019.259999999999990905052982270717620849609375,
        'humidity' => 71,
        'temp_kf' => 0.88000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125,
      ),
      'weather' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 802,
          'main' => 'Clouds',
          'description' => 'scattered clouds',
          'icon' => '03d',
        ),
      ),
      'clouds' => 
      array (
        'all' => 36,
      ),
      'wind' => 
      array (
        'speed' => 4.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125,
        'deg' => 37.00240000000000151203494169749319553375244140625,
      ),
      'sys' => 
      array (
        'pod' => 'd',
      ),
      'dt_txt' => '2018-05-16 09:00:00',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'dt' => 1526472000,
      'main' => 
      array (
        'temp' => 293.6100000000000136424205265939235687255859375,
        'temp_min' => 292.95800000000002683009370230138301849365234375,
        'temp_max' => 293.6100000000000136424205265939235687255859375,
        'pressure' => 1019.799999999999954525264911353588104248046875,
        'sea_level' => 1029.65000000000009094947017729282379150390625,
        'grnd_level' => 1019.799999999999954525264911353588104248046875,
        'humidity' => 66,
        'temp_kf' => 0.66000000000000003108624468950438313186168670654296875,
      ),
      'weather' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 803,
          'main' => 'Clouds',
          'description' => 'broken clouds',
          'icon' => '04d',
        ),
      ),
      'clouds' => 
      array (
        'all' => 56,
      ),
      'wind' => 
      array (
        'speed' => 5.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875,
        'deg' => 38.0009000000000014551915228366851806640625,
      ),
      'sys' => 
      array (
        'pod' => 'd',
      ),
      'dt_txt' => '2018-05-16 12:00:00',
    )
```

I'm trying to get the 'all' values where 'dt_txt' starts from 0am the next day to 0pam the day after.
For now I'm using the following php code without checking for dt_txt:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=D%C3%BClmen,de&mode=json";
$response = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($response);
$t = 0;
$regen = 0;
$regendiv = 0;

  for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $fg = $obj->list[$i]->clouds->all;

    $regen += $fg;
   }
   echo $regen;
 ?>
```

My code requires me to run the request at a specific time (like close to midnight) in order to catch the 'all' values for the next day. Is there any way to check for 'dt_text' = the next day?

My Idea would be something like this:

```
    for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $fg = $obj->list[$i]->clouds->all;

    if (strpos($obj->list[$i]->dt_txt), $date){
    $regen += $fg;
    }
**//But how do I get $date to be the following day**
   }
   echo $regen;
 ?>
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($obj)` and look at the Objects structure!

Comment: But I would still have to check for the date of the following day... I'm not sure how to get that

Comment: Just use `dt` instead of `dt_txt` with simple math - a day has 86400 seconds and `time()` returns the current timestamp. In addition to that, you should care about the timezone

Comment: Didnt think about that one, I'll try that out

Comment: I would say that that data is only for one day. And it appears to be today. Maybe you should check the parameter options you can use on the call that gathers the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (24 * 60 * 60);
$morgen = date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek);


$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=D%C3%BClmen,de&mode=json";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response);


$quote = 0;

   for($i=0; $i < 14; $i++) {


    if (strpos($obj->list[$i]->dt_txt, $morgen) !== false) {
    $fg = $obj->list[$i]->clouds->all;
    if($fg > 80) { $t = 1; }
    $regen += $fg;
    $quote++;


}


   }
  $regendiv = $regen / $quote;

?>
```

Probably  not the prettiest way but it gets the job done.